# Draw a NSImage using cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-graphics, nsview

Currently I am  drawing some shapes using  Bézier Paths on an NSView. Where the drawing code get execute on drawRect: method and creates an image in the end.

I don't want to show this View to the user anywhere. However as I know the  drawRect: method only gets called when we add the view to a superview and thereafter calling display or displayNeedsUpdate methods on NSView.

My requirement is to create an image of my required drawing.

Rather than drawing on to a NSView and converting it to a  PNG , Is there any way we can draw the image directly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an `NSBitmapImageRep` and use `bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:` by specifying your views frame.

The bitmap image representation will be drawn.

Then, you only need to use `representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil` and write the result in a file.

The sample below is extracted from cocoa with love's tutorial: [Advanced drawing using AppKit](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2011/01/advanced-drawing-using-appkit.html)

```
NSRect iconViewFrame = iconView.frame;
[iconView setFrame:[iconView nativeRect]];

NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapImageRep =
    [iconView bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:[iconView frame]];
[iconView
    cacheDisplayInRect:[iconView bounds]
    toBitmapImageRep:bitmapImageRep];
[[bitmapImageRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil]
    writeToURL:[savePanel URL]
    atomically:YES];

[iconView setFrame:iconViewFrame];
```

**They also advise:**

> Creating your own NSBitmapImageRep, setting the NSGraphicsContext
>   using graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:, locking focus yourself and
>   invoking drawRect: directly will avoid these issues and is more
>   flexible. But it would have been more work so I didn't bother for this
>   sample project (I mostly put this export code into the app so I could
>   create the app's icon).

So you may choose the best-suited solution for your needs.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong , this code snippet does is converting the NSView to a PNG , isn't it ? To create the draw the -drawRect method should still get executed isn't it ?

Comment: It is the standard way. But the view **doesn't need to be shown** this way. You just create the view without displaying it. Usually people do the same when needing to print specific portions of their views.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick responses